# Не работают сниппеты в файлах сниппетов в visual studio code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, emmet

Я хочу эффективно создавать сниппеты для visual studio code. Я создал для теста пару на python, в результате, `python.json` выглядит так:

```json
{
    "Comma and space-separated print": {
        "prefix": "comma+",
        "body": "print($1, sep=', ')$0",
        "description": "print a list of items separated with ', '"
    },
    "Comma-separated print": {
        "prefix": "comma",
        "body": "print($1, sep=',')$0",
        "description": "print a list of items separated with ','"
    },
}
```

Тем не менее, я заметил, что это неудобно и долго. К тому же я не хочу использовать расширение snippet generator, хотелось бы писать сниппеты напрямую в файл без вспомогательных интерфейсов. Для этого я решил создать сниппет для json файлов, который создает json-объект с 3 основными св-ами сниппета - prefix, body, description. Я пришел к такому решению:

```
{
    "Template for a code snippet": {
        "prefix": "snip",
        "body": [
            "\"$1\": {",
            "\t\"prefix\": \"$2\",",
            "\t\"body\": \"$3\",",
            "\t\"description\": \"$4\"",
            "}$0",
        ],
        "description": "create a template a for a code snippet"
    }
}
```

Но если я пытаюсь использовать префикс `snip`, в автодополнении ничего нет - только слово из словаря "snippet". С чем это связано? Мое предположение - сниппеты не работают в папке, в которой они хранятся, работают только для файлов, не связанных с самим редактором. Если это так, то как заставить их работать в этой папке (`AppData/Roaming/Code/User/snippets`)?

Comment: Я не уверен что влияние папки — хорошее объяснение причины, в конечном счете это легко проверить. Я предполагаю что дело в расширении файла (то есть в привязке сниппета к языку, а тут json) хотя проверить это сейчас не могу, поэтому комментом.

Comment: Попробую использовать префикс в новом файле в другой папке - возможно, он вообще не рабочий и где то нужно прописать путь к сниппетам вручную

Comment: В новосозданном файле все работает, проблема в расположении json файла - похоже, что он не действует именно в папке со сниппетами. Или попробовать переоткрыть файл вручную, а не через настройки vsc

Comment: Переоткрыть не помогло, может создам папку со сниппетами локально в папке со сниппетами, как бы странно это не звучало, можно же для конкретной папки сниппеты сделать, погуглю

Comment: Новосозданный файл как я понимаю еще не сохранен как json. Ближе к вечеру смогу глянуть пока не за компом. Снипеты должны работать с любыми папками. Пока можете проверить на файле с другим расширением в папке снипетов, например .js и с другим ключевым словом.

Comment: Да, он еще не сохранен, но разве это должно влиять?

Comment: Нашел решение - по умолчанию редактор открывает файлы сниппетов с редактором Code Snippets, заменил на json - помогло, теперь все работает. Теперь другой вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы для файлов со сниппетами не приходилось искусственно менять редактор, чтобы они открывались как голый json по умолчанию?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149388/discussion-between--bro-and-daniil-loban).